# pub/static/_requirejs is not being created in magento 2 version 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, requirejs, deploy, requirejs-config.js

i am trying to include slick plugin into magento 2 through custom theme by requirejs but pub/static/_requirejs folder + files are not being generated on code deploy.
file structure is following:

1. /app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/requirejs-config.js
2. /app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/web/js/slick.js and
   slick.min.js
3. /app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/web/css/source/vendor/slick.less
   and slick-theme.less

Code for requirejs-config.js is as follows:

```
 `var config = {
           paths: {
               slick:'js/slick'
           },
           shim: {
               slick: {
               deps: ['jquery']
               }
           }
       };`
```

This is not a duplicate question, i have not found any solution on internet in last two days. Do let me know if any thing else needed regarding this question if it is not clear.
I have followed this tutorial:
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-slick-carousel/

but i am stuck on point 7 as "requirejs-config.js" is not getting included may be because pub/static/_requirejs folder is not being generated on deploy

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Please help me as i am stuck on this issue from last 2 days

Screenshot of View-source is:
[image: View-source of head block]

Comment: deploy command generates pub/static/frontend, pub/static/adminhtml folders and their needed files but not _requirejs folder

Comment: _requirejs folder creates on magento 2 lower version i.e. on 2.1.x but not on Magento 2.2.x

Comment: then how should I add 3rd party custom plugins in magento 2.2.x through require.js or any other way?

Comment: Do you want to add external js to your website?

Comment: yes.. like slick carousel, scroll bars or any other plugins

Comment: I have created the requirejs-config.js under app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/ and its working fine for me. In the document they are saying to paste it under web but you need to put the requirejs-config.js under theme not web

Comment: If you viewsource the page then you will find the requirejs-config.js. The url will like this: http://example.com/pub/static/version1531144264/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/requirejs-config.js Now find the slick word, you will see that one is now added.

Comment: exactly it should be like this, but in my case i cannot find any file path like this in my view source. can you please check my above code and paths and see if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Delete the requirejs-config.js from pub/static/version/frontend/vendor/theme/requirejs-config.js.. Then run bin/magento cache:clean and flush then run static content deploy. See if it works.

Comment: I don't have any version folder in pub/static , 
pub/static folder structure is like this:
    1- pub/static/frontend
    2- pub/static/adminhtml
    3- .htaccess
    4- deployed_version.txt

and my question is exactly why version folder and  requirejs-config.js file is not being generated in pub/static

Comment: version folder is a virtual it will not been created. skip that folder and goto frontend

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, 
/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_US does have requirejs-config.js file and it also has my code, but still slick is not being initialized and also in view source i cannot find requirejs-config.js file.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of head section of view source and post it your question?

Comment: yes sure. Question updated

Comment: Strange. Your mixins.js and requirejs-config.js not loading. Are you using custom theme if yes then try to change it to default luma theme and test again.

Comment: Tried with luma as default theme, it is still not loading requirejs-config.js

Comment: Do you have any default magento installation because code looks ok for me and its working for me as well. So may be something is wrong with some module or customization you have made.

Comment: this is fresh theme, there are no modules created in app/code, and i tried with luma theme as well it is also not including requirejs-config.js, so this means it is not the issue with theme customization.

Comment: luma theme is working properly? Did you tried to add product in cart etc?

Comment: i have checked properly on luma theme, both requirejs-config.js and mixins.js are getting included, that is interesting. what exactly could be the issue?

Comment: Thanks to @SukumarGorai for help, your luma theme point has helped me to debug all the way. I was creating new layout '1column test' in which i was removing blocks, and removing ' <referenceContainer name="after.body.start"/>'  block was specifically stopping magento to add requirejs-config.js to the page. 
This solved my problem

Comment: Great do you want me add answer?

Comment: Sure. Actual problem and it's solution is in my above comment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79949/discussion-on-question-by-asad-kaleem-pub-static-requirejs-is-not-being-created).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the if **requirejs-config.js** loads **slick** or not on below path:

> pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/requirejs-config.js

If its exist there then check the page by view source if its loads the same there or not on below path:

> http://example.com/pub/static/version1531144264/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/requirejs-config.js

It should load there but according to the screenshot you have shared, requirejs-config.js is not loaded on your browser that means either you have created new layout which removed the block or you have removed some block which add requirejs to the page.

You can debug it by enabling luma theme and also disabled the other customization you have made.

Hope this helps!