# Datatable js include issue in magento2

Tags: magento2, requirejs, js-css, requirejs-config.js

I am including datatable plugin to my custom module.

I tried in this way, below is the code of my **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
 var config = {
    map: {
   '*': {
       dataTables: 'Vendor_Module/js/datatables.min'
     }
   }
 };
```

including css file like below in **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_Module::css/datatables.min.css"/>
</head>
```

And i moved my css and js files into respective folders inside web folder.
 **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/datatables.min.css 
 Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/datatables.min.js**

I have used below code in my template file to load Datatable.

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','dataTables'], function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
});
```

seems datatable is not loading. and getting below error in console.

> Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery

Please anyone suggest me where i am wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check all steps in your module.

Create **requirejs-config.js** at `/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend`

```
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           dataTableJs: 'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.dataTables.min'
       }
   }
};
```

Then, Add css in xml file at `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>      
        <!-- Your content -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Add code in your phtml file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','dataTableJs'], function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
});
```

Now, execute this command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```

Go to `pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Namespace/Theme/en_US/requirejs-config.js` and find this below line available in this file or not.

```
dataTableJs: 'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.dataTables.min'
```

Under `pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Namespace/Theme/en_US`, delete the file requirejs-config.js.

Refresh your page and it will be generated again with new content.

If it doesn't work delete the requirejs-config.js and run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
```

Comment: hi @Rohan, what i am missing there, i am also doing the same is it?

Comment: Did you deploy after add js in requirejs-config? Please check in pub/static that your code available in that file or not?

Comment: yes, i deployed, files are there, i checked

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Please check in that file that your file line available or not.

Comment: I don't have any file called _requirejs inside pub/static, have only frontend,adminhtml folders and deployed_version file

Comment: You can take reference from here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/232918/51810

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84575/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rohan-hapani).